Is there a reason the LED current is being limited this way?
I'm reviewing an older schematic that was drafted by someone else, and I noticed that for the LED circuit, they are controlling the LED with a NPN transistor. But the LED is connected to the Collector, and what looks like the LED current limiting resistor is connected to the emitter.
I'm having a hard time understanding what the design intent was, since the designer could have put the resistor in series with the LED on the collector side, and connected the Emitter to GND. The LED-1 signal is outputing 3.3V to the base, so I don't think adding the resistor to the emitter would be the best thing to do because of the low base voltage, since the goal is to just turn on the LED.
I'm just looking for feedback on if there's a reason for putting a current limiting resistor on the Emitter side instead of the collector side. LED has a forward voltage of 6V @ 100mA. I can't share the datasheet since this component isn't searchable in the US (it's component from a Chinese  distributor).


My first thought when reading your question was "Why would you not drive a LED like this?"

"LED has a forward voltage of 6V @ 100mA." Is this a LED or LEDs in series? More likely, the latter...

@Circuitfantasist -- Here is a single LED having four chips or dies.  Here's the DigiKey link for the LED.  Here's a DigiKey search that shows you many. I have seen 40W dollar store bulbs that have only 5 LEDS to drop >100V. Planned obsolescence!

The emitter resistor forms a negative feedback loop to regulate the current. This design (sort of) fixes the LED current at 100mA, compensating for variations in the 8V rail and the LED forward voltage, and to a lesser extent, transistor DC current gain.
To answer the question, the designer felt this regulation was necessary to ensure consistent LED brightness, limit the LED current to the datasheet value, or both.
To be perfectly honest, the design is kind of weak. I'll explain why, and show how to improve it below.
But first… How does it work?
When 'LED-1' control input is high, current flows through the base resistor and forward biases the base-emitter junction to about 0.7V (Vbe), turning the transistor on. Base current is set by the resistor, and by the difference between logic-high and Vbe.
You state that the logic input as 3.3V. This is kind of important, since we're using that fixed voltage to set base current.
Before we discuss how the emitter resistor helps, let's try it with a grounded "common" emitter, that is, no resistor at all.
With LED-1 at 3.3V, we will have base voltage (Vbe) at about 0.7V. There will be (3.3V-0.7V) = 2.6V across the 1k base resistor. Ohm’s Law tells us that the resistor, and thus the base current, will be 2.6mA.
Let's set the transistor DC current gain (beta, \$\beta\$) to be 100. Result? We will have a little less than 260mA at the collector feeding the LED.
That is,

Collector current (Ic) = Base current (Ib) x \$\beta\$
Ic = Ib x \$\beta\$ = 2.6mA x 100 = 260mA.

Let's verify that with a sim (simulate it here):

Sure enough, a bit less than 260mA. Clearly, that's more current than we want. But, we can also observe that the LED (collector, Ic) current will be constant, even if we change the LED supply voltage (try the voltage slider.)
This is because Vbe doesn't change, so Ib doesn't change. Since collector current Ic = Ib x \$\beta\$, and this condition will hold over a reasonable range of collector voltage, Ic doesn't change, either. We have current regulation.
Could we adjust the base current just by changing the 1k resistor to 2.6k? Yes, this will yield 100mA for \$\beta\$=100.
There's still a problem. Real transistor \$\beta\$ varies widely. Without any current feedback, \$\beta\$ has a 1:1 influence on the collector current (try the beta slider and prepare to be disappointed.)
The MMBT8050 datasheet shows a DC current gain range (labeled hFE, but for our purposes is the same as \$\beta\$) of 100 to 600. Using 1k ohm on the base as shown, we get an Ic range of 100mA up to a staggering 1.2A! That LED would go 'pop' in short order.
What to do?
We could choose to limit the LED current the ‘normal’ way, with a load resistor of 19 ohms on the collector side. 1k on the base assures we'd be driving the transistor into saturation, so \$\beta\$ is not such an issue anymore.
Assuming a stable 8V LED supply and reasonably repeatable LED forward voltage, using a collector-side load will yield decent if not perfect brightness consistency. This is why that approach is popular.
But... we're being fussy about brightness. More importantly, perhaps we want to not fry our expensive LED if the 8V supply goes too high (from a battery, say.)
We'll need to regulate the LED drive with some kind of current sensing feedback that compensates not just for those factors, but for \$\beta\$ as well.
Insert the resistor back to the emitter side. The resistor creates an emitter feedback, a self-bias that responds to increases in Ic/Ie by raising Ve and Vb, which reduces Ib.
This cancels some of the \$\beta\$ variation, while continuing to provide constant current in response to LED supply and forward voltage.
We can make an appropriate bias arrangement to get LED current regulation 'for free', without any added components.
How to design this?
We start with a first approximation: \$\beta\$=100 and base current Ib=1mA, to yield 100mA at the collector.
That is,

I(led) = Ic = (Ib x \$\beta\$) = (1mA x 100) mA

Logic-high voltage is 3.3V, and the base resistor is 1k. To get 1mA of base current, we want 1V of IR drop across the resistor. That means the base voltage should be (3.3V-1V) = 2.3V.
That is,

Vb = 3.3V - (1mA x 1k) = 2.3V

How to get that 2.3V at the base? Remember, the emitter resistor lifts the emitter voltage in response to current. The base voltage will be about 0.7V (Vbe) above that.
Working backwards, we can compute the target emitter voltage (Ve) to achieve that condition as:

Ve = (3.3V - (Resistor IR drop) - Vbe)

or:

Ve = (3.3V - 1V - 0.7V) = 1.6V

Recall that emitter current is Ic + Ib. Again, using \$\beta\$=100 and Ib=1mA we have:

Ie = (Ic + Ib) = (\$\beta\$ + 1) x Ib = 101mA

Our bias condition will be Ib=1mA, Vb=2.3V, Ve=1.6V, all at Ie=101mA. Finally, we have the information we need to choose the emitter resistor:

Re = Ve / Ie

or:

Re = 1.6V/101mA = 15.8 ohms.

Not coincidentally, that's pretty close to the schematic value. But 15.8 ohms actually results in a current that's a bit too low. Why? Because Vbe varies with collector current. Actual Vbe will be somewhat more than 0.7V, so base current will be somewhat less than our 1mA target. (Spoiler alert: with 15.8 ohms Ic comes in at about 99mA, which is really quite ok.)
Nevertheless, the design uses 15 ohms for the emitter. Let's see what it does in simulation (simulate it here):

Result? About 102mA at the LED. Mouse-over the transistor: the sim shows Vbe at 715mV. Our slightly-smaller emitter resistor compensated for our slightly-larger Vbe. Close enough.
Now, try the beta slider. Indeed, Ic is less sensitive to \$\beta\$ than without the emitter feedback. With higher \$\beta\$ the emitter current increases, raising the base voltage and decreasing base current; with lower \$\beta\$ emitter current decreases, lowering base voltage and increasing base current. That's the negative feedback in action.
We've successfully compensated for some of the effect of \$\beta\$. But not all of it.
Design tip: you can optimize emitter feedback by making the emitter resistor as large as possible, and the base resistor as small as possible.
More about transistor feedback and biasing here: https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/semiconductors/chpt-4/biasing-calculations/
How doesn't it work?
Nailed it, right? Well, yes and no.
On paper this design hits our LED current target, so long as we have an ideal 3.3V logic-high and transistor \$\beta\$ of 100.
Logic-high sensitivity isn't such a problem as we can assume this comes from a regulated supply. We can safely ignore that.
There will be some series resistance in the logic driver however, which will add to the base resistor and thus decrease current. This could be quite a lot if a weak drive strength is used.
There is however still enough \$\beta\$ sensitivity that makes it impossible to get repeatable brightness results. Even transistors pre-screened for consistent \$\beta\$ will vary with temperature.
As you dig into the MMBT8050 sheet, they show four hFE screening options, spanning the 100-600 \$\beta\$ range. You could specify the 'P' version (100-200).
Using highest \$\beta\$=200 and LED supply at just 8.8V, the LED current hits over 127mA.
In short, as designed, the original circuit will not give repeatable LED brightness in production, and at the extremes of voltage, \$\beta\$ and temperature, could actually burn up the LED. It's that bad.
How can we fix it?
We can fix these issues by adding a second transistor in the feedback loop, as below (simulate it here):

You may recognize this as the classic 2-transistor current limiter. It works differently than the single-transistor design: the feedback transistor adds gain to the feedback, strongly amplifying any emitter (sense) resistor voltage in excess of its Vbe of 0.6V. The more the feedback's base voltage rises above 0.6V, the more transistor base current it shunts away.
Result? Tight emitter current regulation to 0.6V, regardless of \$\beta\$, or for that matter, a fairly wide range of logic-high voltage.
We see that Ve only 0.6V. Why?  Remember that Ic influences Vbe. The feedback transistor's Vbe collector current is much lower, less than 2mA, compared to the pass transistor which is carrying 100mA.
To get 100mA we adjust the resistor down to 6 ohms: Ve=600mV / Ie=100mA becomes the new regulation point.
What makes it better? The regulated current depends mainly on the sense resistor and feedback transistor's Vbe bias, neither of which change vary much. With the active feedback gain, we overcome the pass transistor \$\beta\$ variation, cancelling almost all of its influence.
Go try those beta and voltage sliders again. Be not disappointed that the LED current doesn't change.
Besides less \$\beta\$ sensitivity, a few more bonuses of active feedback:

Not as sensitive to logic-high voltage
Not as sensitive to base resistor value
Smaller sense R = more overhead voltage for the pass transistor (can regulate to lower supply / greater LED forward drop)

Now you have something you can build with confidence. You don't have to select special transistors, and you get better LED voltage compliance range.
Fun fact: you could even replace the pass NPN with a MOSFET and the circuit will work the same way, with reduced current draw from the I/O pin.
And here's what that looks like (simulate it here):

The biggest benefit is that with 10k in series, the I/O pin draw is only 115 uA, making it less sensitive to drive pin drive strength. Since the feedback transistor Ic is reduced, we also dial down the FET source sense resistor to compensate for that transistor's decreased Vbe. Otherwise, works the same as the 2-transistor version.

"The ensuing IR drop across it raises the emitter voltage, which in turn raises the base voltage."? and "...this also raises the base voltage which reduces the base current"?

caveat for your fun fact: 3.3 V logic only leaves about 2.7 V to turn on the MOSFET which might be too little for some MOSFETs.

"Any increase in collector current (by an increase in 8V, say) is cancelled out by the increasing base voltage, a consistent 1 Vbe higher than the emitter" is not true. The base voltage must stay constant when the emitter voltage increases so Vbe decreases, and the current is restored.

Is the 100K still useful or necessary in the classic 2-transistor current limiter version?

The pull-down prevents noise pickup if the micro’s I/O goes 3-state, so yes it’s still helpful with the 2-transistor version.

If we ignore the base current, the voltage at the emitter of the 8050 will be about 2.6V, which should result in about 170mA of LED current. The current will be fairly independent of the LED forward drop, which is a good thing. On the other hand, the current is quite sensitive to the 3.3V rail voltage and the voltage drop in whatever is driving the input. It's also quite sensitive to the transistor hFE. With likely hFE values eg. PJSEMI of 100 to 400 depending on beta bin and Lady luck, the voltage drop across the 1kΩ resistor will be significant and the current will likely be more in the 130mA range.
I have a model of the SS8050, which is a similar part with a nominal gain of 218 (the old Motorola trick was to take a TO-92 number and change '2N' to "MMBT' for the same die in SOT-23). So let's model it:

So very inaccurate and not repeatable in production, not very stable with temperature, and the transistor will burn out if the LED is on continuously. Other than those points..
One possible reason for the troublesome 1kΩ resistor is to limit loading of the driver should the LED become disconnected (it will effectively be connected to a 15Ω resistor to ground through a diode should that happen). Or maybe they just didn't understand the circuit.

The emitter resistor serves as a negative feedback to limit the current by decreasing the base-emitter voltage and thus base current when the emitter current increases.
If you connect the resistor on the collector side, there will be no feedback, and the only current-limiting element will be the resistor whose current will depend on the voltage applied across, its own temperature, the LED temperature and the transistor temperature.
On the collector side the current will be completely dependent on (and changed greatly by) possibly great variations in the supply voltage, while on the emitter side the current will not be influenced by the 8V LED supply and will be defined by the typically well-regulated and stable 3.3V supply of the MCU which typically is the control input for a circuit like this one.

Although there are issues with power dissipation and base current causing voltage drop in the 1k resistor, as described by Spehro, the general technique of feeding an LED from a current source is useful if the power for the LED (VCC-8V in this case) is not stable.
With a simple resistor feed for the LED the current would vary with the supply, with this approach the current would be stable and defined by the 3.3V supply and the 15 ohm resistor.

Note also that the transistor is operating in the linear mode, so will dissipate power according to its voltage drop and current.  Putting the resistor in the collector in series with the LED means the transistor is now operating as a switch with most of the current limiting dissipation occurring in the resistor.

@CarlRutschow - but that would stop it working as a constant current source. The LED current would vary in proportion with the supply voltage. - this may not be the goal. Yes, if the transistor is intended to act as a current source it needs to be heat sinked to deal with the worst case power. If it used as a switch that power must be dissipated by the resistor which needs to be appropriately rated.

It's possible they just wanted to operate the bipolar in mild saturation with \$\beta\approx 100\$ and with \$V_{_\text{CE}}\approx 500\:\text{mV}\$ and using an emitter resistor to provide local NFB via emitter degeneration.
A very quick calculation then says \$R_{_\text{E}}=\frac{8\:\text{V}-6\:\text{V}-500\:\text{mV}}{100\:\text{mA}}=15\:\Omega\$ and with \$V_{_\text{BE}}=700^+\:\text{mV}\$, the base resistor had to drop about \$1\:\text{V}\$ with \$I_{_\text{B}}=1\:\text{mA}\$ so that means \$1\:\text{k}\Omega\$ there. The \$100\:\text{k}\Omega\$ completes the picture without materially impacting the design approach.

Looking for the general idea
It would be beneficial to conclude with a "philosophy" of the problem, summarizing the abundance of practical answers and advice (as they say, "to see the forest for the trees"). The advantage of this functional approach is that we can transfer the specific insights gained from studying this particular circuit to a multitude of similar circuits, thus enabling us to see the connections between them.
How can we achieve this?
To this end, we can replace the specific semiconductor devices with simpler and more understandable basic electrical elements connected in conceptual diagrams. These will be a kind of "electrical analogies" of semiconductor circuits.
How do LED and BJT behave?
In order to proceed, we must have a basic understanding of the two primary elements in the circuit: the LED and the BJT. This involves grasping their general behavior (without getting into the specifics of their internal structure) within this particular circuit.
In general terms, both are dynamic resistors (nonlinear elements whose static resistance changes), but they exhibit opposite characteristics when the current through them (or voltage across them) varies.
LEDs reduce their (static) resistance R as the current I rises, thereby maintaining a constant voltage drop V = I.R across them. So they behave as constant-voltage resistors.
BJTs increase their (static) resistance R as the voltage V rises, thereby maintaining a constant current I = V/R through them. So they behave as constant-current resistors.
In this way, we can simulate LEDs and BJTs with variable resistors by adjusting their resistance to mimic the desired behavior.
Constant-voltage resistor supplied through a constant ohmic resistor

I'm having a hard time understanding what the design intent was, since the designer could have put the resistor in series with the LED on the collector side, and connected the Emitter to GND.

Real circuit
In this configuration, when the transistor is on it is fully saturated.  The voltage across the collector-emitter section is almost 0 V, or, figuratively speaking, its "resistance" is 0 Ω. So the circuit consists only of an LED and a resistor in series supplied by Vcc.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The resistor is used to dissipate the excess voltage (Vcc - V = 5 - 3 = 2 V) from the power supply. Without a resistor, the LED will attempt to maintain its forward voltage (3 V) by decreasing its resistance. This will cause an excessive current flow, leading to the LED's or transistor's destruction.
Conceptual circuit
Let's now simulate the LED by a variable resistor Rv and consider this configuration in three successive steps where we step up the supply voltage and observe what the "LED" does.
Vcc = 5 V: In this initial state, the "LED" has set Rv = 150 Ω at which a current I = 5/(150 + 100) = 20 mA flows.

simulate this circuit
Vcc = 10 V: When we increase Vcc with 5 V, the current increases to 70 mA but, at the same time, the "LED" decreases its resistance to 43 Ω. Thus it keeps its voltage V = 0.07*43 = 3 V unchanged.

simulate this circuit
Vcc = 15 V: If we increase Vcc by another 5 V, the current increases to 120 mA but the "LED" decreases its resistance to 25 Ω. Thus it keeps its voltage V = 0.120*25 = 3 V unchanged.

simulate this circuit
So, in this arrangement, the constant resistor does not compensate for the Vcc variations. The current and accordingly the brightness of the LED varies.
Constant-voltage resistor supplied through a constant-current resistor
Apparently, the circuit is the same, but there is a very significant difference in the operation of the transistor.  While above it was saturated (switched on), here it is semi-conducting, or as they say, operating in active mode. This means that it changes the voltage ("resistance") between the collector and the emitter, and thus can adjust the current through the LED.
Real circuit
In order to get the transistor to operate in this active mode where it has the property of keeping the current constant, we need to get it out of saturation. To do this, we can reduce the base current by increasing the resistance of the base resistor Rb or (better) reduce the base-emitter voltage by adding another resistor Rbe and thus making a voltage divider.

simulate this circuit
Conceptual circuit
Vcc = 5 V: As in Schematic 1.2, the "LED" has set Rv = 150 Ω at which a current I = 20 mA flows.

simulate this circuit
Vcc = 10 V: However, when we increase Vcc with 5 V, something different happens than in Schematic 1.3 - the "LED" does not react but the transistor increases its resistance to 350 Ω thus keeping its collector current I = Vcc/(Rv + Ri) = 10/(150 + 350) = 20 mA unchanged.

simulate this circuit
Vcc = 15 V: Even if we increase Vcc by another 5 V, the "LED" does not change its resistance but the transistor increases its resistance to 600 Ω thus keeping its collector current I = 15/(150 + 600) = 20 mA unchanged.

simulate this circuit
So, in this arrangement, the transistor behaves as a dynamic resistor that compensates for the Vcc variations, so the brightness of the LED is constant.
Constant-voltage resistor supplied through a constant-current source

But the LED is connected to the Collector, and what looks like the LED current limiting resistor is connected to the emitter.

The best way to make the transistor keep the current through the LED constant, and thus its brightness constant, is to introduce negative feedback.
Real circuit
For this purpose, we can move the resistor from the collector to the emitter, with which we force the transistor to keep the voltage across it constant and hence the current through it constant.

simulate this circuit
Conceptual circuit
As above, the "transistor" is semi-conducting, (operating in active mode). This means that it changes the voltage ("resistance") between the collector and the emitter, and thus adjusting the current through the LED. But now it does not do it mechanically, but by monitoring and keeping the voltage across the resistor R constant (2 V).
Vcc = 5 V: The "LED" has set Rv = 150 Ω and the "BJT" Ri = 0 so a current I = Vcc/(Rv + Ri + R) = 5/(150 + 0 + 100) = 20 mA flows.

simulate this circuit
Vcc = 10 V: When we increase Vcc with 5 V, as usual, the "LED" does not react but the transistor increases its resistance to 250 Ω thus keeping its collector current I = Vcc/(Rv + Ri + R) = 10/(150 + 250 + 100) = 20 mA unchanged.

simulate this circuit
Vcc = 15 V: If we increase Vcc by another 5 V, as before, the "LED" does not change its resistance but the transistor increases its resistance to 500 Ω thus keeping its collector current I = 15/(150 + 500 + 100) = 20 mA unchanged.

simulate this circuit
So, when Vcc changes, only the voltage across the "transistor" changes (with the same rate); the voltages across the "LED" and the resistor R do not change.
In this arrangement, the combination of a transistor and emitter resistor behave as a current source (sink) that compensates for the Vcc variations. As a result, the brightness of the LED is constant.
